# ReactJS router links not working when clicking them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have the following basic `ReactJS` but it doesn't change the routes.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-testing-routes?file=src%2Fpages%2FPage1.jsx

Demo: https://react-testing-routes.stackblitz.io/page3

Here you have the source code:

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Page1 from './pages/Page1';
import Page2 from './pages/Page2';
import Page3 from './pages/Page3';
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Page1 } />
        <Route path="/page2" component={Page2 } />
        <Route path="/page2" component={Page3 } />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

**Page1.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Page1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      letter: 'A',
    };
  }

  render() {
    return <>
      <div>You are currently on: Page 1 (Letter: {this.state.letter})</div>
      <Link to="/page2">Page 2</Link><br />
      <Link to="/page3">Page 3</Link><br />
    </>;
  }
}

export default Page1;
```

**Page2.jsx**

```
// similar as Page1.jsx
```

**Page3.jsx**

```
// similar as Page1.jsx
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "latest"
  }
}
```

Any idea on how to make it change the routes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `exact` prop, otherwise `/page2` will be matched by `/`:

```
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Page1} />
    <Route exact path="/page2" component={Page2} />
    <Route exact path="/page3" component={Page3} />
  </Switch>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-testing-routes-ktkwg5?file=src.jsx

Answer (score 0):

use `exact`

```
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Page1 } />
        <Route path="/page2" component={Page2 } />
        <Route path="/page2" component={Page3 } />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```